# How to include jars of Eclipse project's classpath in pom.xml

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jar

I have an Eclipse Maven project with a Referenced Libraries folder. This folder contains the same jars that are included in project's actual classpath. To compile the project using Maven, when I use

```
 mvn clean install
```

it cannot get the jars which are in classpath. So I tried using the following

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Whenever I try to compile, it gives me errors stating that it could not find the classes, those classes which I have already added on the classpath of the project.

I also tried

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>/Referenced Libraries</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

but it doesn't do anything. What am I doing wrong ? How do I make the pom.xml file to get jars from the project's classpath in order to compile the project? Any help will be appreciated please. Thank You.

Comment: Usually, with  build tools like Maven, there is a section that defines the dependencies.  This is where you would add your list of JARs.  If memory serves, in Maven you can also specify if it's a compile-time, run-time, or test dependency.

Comment: So if I have 50 jars those are dependencies, then I will need to add all of them in pom.xml? Isn't there a way to tell Maven to pick up jars from project's classpath?

Comment: No. You're doing it backwards. First, you maintain the POM with your dependencies, and then Eclipse will automatically read it with m2e.

Comment: You've got things backwards; maven should "own" the list of dependencies and then Eclipse's m2e plugin will manage the Eclipse .classpath to match what's in the pom.

Comment: Could you please explain "own" the list of dependencies please. Way I understand is that when I start creating a maven project, I just add import statements to a class. Eclipse adds corresponding jars to classpath. I dont see any changes at that time in pom.xml. Once I run `mvn clean install`, it compiles perfectly without a problem. So when did I ask Maven to own the dependencies?

Comment: You asked it to own the dependencies when you made it a Maven project. This is one of the main reasons people even *use* Maven.